# Update game content via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, game, ajax

On my application, I have a JavaScript cycle that updates tag contents on my page regularly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var players = [];
    players.push($('#p0'));
    players.push($('#p1'));
    players.push($('#p2'));
    players.push($('#p3'));
    i=0;
    /*
     * cycle through the players.
     */
    function cyclePlayer() {
        players[i].parents(".card-header").addClass('border-success');
        players[i].load('play.php?p='+i);
        i = ++i % players.length;
        $('#deck').load('play.php?deck=1');
        $('#pile').load('play.php?pile=1');
        $('#feedback').load('play.php?feedback=1');
    }
    PlayerLoop = setInterval('cyclePlayer()', 1500 );

    $("#stop").click(function(){
        clearInterval(PlayerLoop);
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $('#deck').load('play.php?reset=1');
        location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

The server code that is being called looks like this:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

use Svc\Myapp\FrontHandler;

$myApp = new FrontHandler();

if (isset($_GET['p']) && !isset($_SESSION['winner'])) {
    echo $myApp->playerTurn();
}

if (isset($_GET['deck'])) {
    echo $myApp->deckUpdate();
}

if (isset($_GET['pile'])) {
    echo $myApp->pileUpdate();
}

if (isset($_GET['feedback'])) {
    echo $myApp->feedbackUpdate();
}
```

Is this production quality code? Is there a way to refactor it to improve it?

Comment: Considering your `<?php` tag never closes, I would say no.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Not closing the PHP tag is actually good practice, if the file has just PHP in it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219383/why-do-some-scripts-omit-the-closing-php-tag

Comment: This still doesn't fit the site's guidelines.  It isn't clear what you're trying to do with the code.  And the title should be more descriptive and less prescriptive.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am only commenting on style now. Variables should be defined with a keyword like `var`, `const` or `let`. They should start with a lowercase character. `PlayerLoop = setInterval('cyclePlayer()', 1500 );` is a nono. Define it with `var` or `let` like this `let playerLoop = setInterval('cyclePlayer()', 1500 );`.

Answer (score 3):

My answer focuses on the ajax requests.

Why 4 requests at each 1500 milliseconds **to the same file** (`play.php`)?

I would do only one request and I would "cycle" on a delay starting from the success callback... instead of a fixed interval, which does not take the request delay in account.

```
var players = [ // No need to use a push method when you already know the array content.
  $('#p0'),
  $('#p1'),
  $('#p2'),
  $('#p3')
];

i=0;

function cyclePlayer() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "play.php",
    data: {iteration:i},
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: (data)=>{

      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));  // See all the infos in the same request response.
      json = JSON.parse(data);

      players[i].html(json.playerTurn).parents(".card-header").addClass('border-success');

      i = ++i % players.length;

      $('#deck').html(json.deckUpdate);
      $('#pile').html(json.pileUpdate);
      $('#feedback').html(json.feedbackUpdate);

      PlayerLoop = setTimeout(cyclePlayer,1500);    // From here, set a new 1500ms timeout.
    },
    error: ()=>{

    },
  });
}

// on load, start a timeout.
var PlayerLoop = setTimeout(cyclePlayer, 1500 );

$("#stop").click(function(){
    clearTimeout(PlayerLoop);
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  location.reload(true);  // true is to reload from server instead of possibly loading from cache.
});
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
use Svc\Myapp\FrontHandler;

if(!isset($_GET['iteration'])){die();}


$myApp= new FrontHandler();

if(!isset($_SESSION['winner'])){
  $results["playerTurn"] = $myApp->playerTurn();
}
$results["deckUpdate"] = $myApp->deckUpdate();
$results["pileUpdate"] = $myApp->pileUpdate();
$results["feedbackUpdate"] = $myApp->feedbackUpdate();

$results["isSetWinner"] = isset($_SESSION['winner']);

// Echo the array as a json. This will be the response of the request.
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Now, I could not test the above... I hope It does not have any typo.

Answer (score 3):

Louys already suggested simplifying the multiple requests into a single request - that is a great idea. I see a few other simplifications and suggestions.

The first few lines of the Javascript code push jQuery objects into an array:

> ```
> var players = [];
> players.push($('#p0'));
> players.push($('#p1'));
> players.push($('#p2'));
> players.push($('#p3'));
> ```

While it isn't the same, one simplification would be to combine those selectors into a single selector:

```
var players = $('#p0, #p1, #p2, #p3');
```

Instead of an array of jQuery objects, that would be a single jQuery object with the four elements, and thus access to each element could be utilized via the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method - e.g.

```
players.eq(i).parents(".card-header").addClass('border-success');
players.eq(i).load('play.php?p='+i);
```

Another consideration is to use a class name - for example, if those four elements all have the same [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute, then that class name could be used in the selector.

---

As Louy's answer suggests, it would be wise to handle the case when the AJAX requests fail - for an example, see the last example in the [documentation for `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

---

Also, as Louy's answer implied, it would be wise to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to send data in JSON format from the PHP code, and then parse it in the AJAX success callback - even if there was a single set of data.

---

The code for the `FrontHandler` class was not included but we see that it has methods like `playerTurn`, `deckUpdate`, etc. Do you consider that class a controller? Perhaps it could have a single method to return the appropriate data based on the supplied parameters.